# Probability problem. Help me figure out the error. (Rabbits attack Wolves and Vice versa)

Tags: probability

I have a solution to this problem, but there is no suitable answer. Help me find an error in logical reasoning and get an answer. (Solution at the end)

On Earth, after a sudden evolutionary change, hares became carnivorous and started hunting wolves, while wolves remained carnivorous and did not change their diet.

When observing one individual, the scientist noticed that this hare has a habit of making supplies by hunting two wolves at once. Statistics show that the hare always starts the attack and, having attacked each of the two wolves in turn, with a probability of `p1 = 0.6` catches a wolf. If the wolf does not become a victim of the hare, then, regardless of the fate of another wolf, it begins to hunt the attacking hare itself and with a probability of `p2 = 0.81` 
catches the offending hare.

Find the probability that in the next fight between two wolves and one hare, one animal will die, no matter who. Write the answer down to the nearest ten thousandth.

$1)$ $0.3058$

$2)$ $0.2841$

$3)$ $0.0144$

$4)$ $0.1998$

**My solution assumes the following**: 
There are $4$ scenarios, when one animal is caught, we have the probability:

$1)$ $0.6 × 0.4 × 0.19$ (Caught the wolf, but could not catch the wolf $2$, wolf $2$ also did not catch a rabbit).

$2)$ $0.4 × 0.81$ (hare)

$3)$ $0.4 × 0.19 × 0.6$ (The second wolf caught the hare)

$4)$ $0.4 × 0.19 × 0.4 × 0.81$ (At the end of the second wolf, the hare was caught)

To further summarize $(1,2,3,4)$, but we haven't answer (= $0.439824$)

The hare will attack the wolf first. First one, then the other. With a chance of $0.6$, he will catch a wolf (any. Chance $0.6$ on one, chance $0.6$ on the other) With a chance of 1 - $0.6$, the wolf will not be caught, which means that it will immediately start attacking the hare with a probability of$ 0.81$. This is how I understood it. If you have a way to get at least the answer and the above and the reasoning is built in accordance with the rules of probability, then you may have understood the problem correctly. I also had some problems understanding the problem, but I offered you a condition and how I understood it.

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear.  Should we read it as asking for the probability that $\textit {exactly}$ one animal dies?  My instincts would have been to read it as asking for the probability that $\textit {at least}$ one animal dies.

Comment: Should add:  if the question is asking about $\textit {exactly}$ one casualty, then I don't see how to answer it, as we aren't told how likely it is that the hare will kill both wolves as opposed to simply one.  On the other hand, if it is asking about the probability that $\textit {at least}$ one animal dies, then the answer seems to obviously be $>.6$ since there is a $.6$ chance that the hare will kill at least one wolf.

Comment: Or is the $.6$ the probability that the hare kills a given wolf?  And if that's the case, then does the first wolf, having survived the assault, immediately counterattack or does it patiently stand by while the murderous hare goes after the second wolf?  But, really, I think we are being asked to do a whole lot of guessing here.  I think the problem should be rewritten for clarity.

Comment: I have updated now

Comment: And are you assuming that the question is asking about exactly one casualty or at least one casualty?

Comment: Note:  if I assume sequential attacks and I assume that you are asking about exactly one casualty then I also get $0.439824$ which leads me to believe that one or more of the guesses made in interpreting the problem were incorrect.

Comment: To stress:  in that reading, then one obviously good scenario is "the hare fails to kill wolf $1$, but then dies at the hand of wolf $1$".  That's exactly one dead, yes?  Wolf $2$ never comes into play.  And the probability of that scenario is $.4\times .81=.324$ which is already greater than all of the available options.

Comment: There is a suggestion if you try to follow a different scenario (the hare will attack with two attacks at once, then the wolves. Wolves can eventually attack even when caught)? If the answer matches the suggested ones, then this solution can be considered correct. I'm stumped

Comment: I'd say you have a reverse engineering problem here.  The problem is so poorly worded that there are all kinds of interpretations available.  Just try one after the other until you get an answer that appears on the list.  There's a clue, I suppose, in the fact that all the available answers are so small.  But, of course, this supposes that whoever set the problem had a coherent interpretation in mind and that they did the math correctly.

Comment: I'm going over the options again. I agree that the person who came up with the problem formulated the condition poorly

Comment: My guess would be that the hare attacks both wolves at the same time.  That's the only way I see to eliminate the $.324$ scenario in which the hare is killed in the battle with wolf $1$.  I suggest assuming that the hare attacks both and that it has an independent $.6$ probability of killing either of the individual wolves.

Comment: Side note:  I can't think about this further right now.  Good luck!